# How to Plot Input and predicted data on graph in tensorflow jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am using tensorflow in jupyter notebook. I have some data which i have trained. Data is in the following form

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
```

Now i am predicting values which are in this form after using linear classifier

```
[{'class_ids': array([1], dtype=int64),
  'classes': array([b'1'], dtype=object),
  'logits': array([ -0.88531315,  12.51075077, -14.0423975 ,   2.56915855], dtype=float32),
  'probabilities': array([  1.52104417e-06,   9.99950290e-01,   2.93827636e-12,
           4.81282150e-05], dtype=float32)},
 {'class_ids': array([3], dtype=int64),
  'classes': array([b'3'], dtype=object),
  'logits': array([  6.42214537,  21.82447243, -13.30796623,  23.08537292], dtype=float32),
  'probabilities': array([  4.51742359e-08,   2.20818907e-01,   1.21958252e-16,
           7.79181063e-01], dtype=float32)},
 {'class_ids': array([2], dtype=int64),
  'classes': array([b'2'], dtype=object),
  'logits': array([  27.05874252,  -58.91906357,   48.28507996, -113.13697052], dtype=float32),
  'probabilities': array([  6.04670480e-10,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
           0.00000000e+00], dtype=float32)},
```

Now i want to plot them on graph. Problem is that i can not do that due to this error

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

How can i resolve this.
This is the code i am using

```
pred_inpuy_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=testCal,
                                                     batch_size=10,
                                                     num_epochs=1,
                                                     shuffle=False)
predictions = model.predict(pred_inpuy_func)
Latest_Pred = list(predictions)
import matplotlib.pyplot as pt
%matplotlib inline
pt.plot(y_test,my_pred,".")
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Do you want to know how you can extract values from your dictionary (follow-up: In what format would you want the data from the sample dict you have provided?)? Do you want to know how to plot in python (follow-up: What kind of plot are you even looking for?)? Regarding the error message you have posted: what is the code that produced this error and what were you attempting to do with it (expected output etc)?

Comment: Regarding your PS: Suggested edits are not to distract from your question or hinder the question answer process. Instead they are meant to increase readability etc so your question will actually get MORE attention. You should be happy when someone takes the time to make such a suggestion to you, seeing that you are quite new to this site

Comment: Yes, this is my 3rd day here :) I am new but people are only giving me suggestions not answer. Thanks for your kind reply

Comment: oh, i was plotting dict on matplotlib. How can i extract predicted values from dict and store them in a string or int. I want to plot test data and predicted values on graph

Comment: "Please do not correct my question by sending edit suggestion" is a strange statement from a beginner asking for assistance, especially when you don't include the actual *code* you have tried and produced the error...

Comment: Well yesterday i got 10 edit suggestion but no answer for my question and those edit suggestion were all same. Just common typing mistakes.

Comment: I have added code now and also removed PS comment :)

Comment: actually i am trying to plot test_data and predicted values on a single graph.